# Grid Splitter and MinWidth

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I am trying to set a `MinWidth` for my columns.

`MinWidth` works correctly for `Column` 0 but not `Column` 2. The splitter just keeps dragging and I can get the Column to be less than the declared `MinWidth`
The `MinWidth` seems to only take effect if the `Column Width` has a numeric value rather than Auto.... Is there a way to get that to work with `Auto` or just `*` ??

Any ideas?

```
    <!-- Content Area -->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
          Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="32" Width="260"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="100" Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Navigation  -->
        <ItemsControl Name="NavigationRegion" 
                  Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="NavigationRegion"
                  Grid.Column="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
        <!-- Splitter -->
        <controls:GridSplitter x:Name="GridSplitter" 
                               Grid.Column="1" 
                               VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                               Background="{StaticResource SplitterBackgroundColor}" 
                               Width="8" 
                               UseLayoutRounding="True" 
                               BorderThickness="1"     
                               BorderBrush="Black"  
                               Height="Auto"/>
        <!-- Form -->
        <ItemsControl x:Name="MainRegion"
                      Grid.Column="2" 
                      Regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>


    </Grid>
```

Comment: and another +1 for highlighting a flaw in the grid splitter. Good question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I fixed this is to set a `MaxWidth` for `Column` 0.
When `SizeChanged` fires I get the `MaxWidth` value for `Column` 0 based upon the current `ActualWidth`

So I removed my `MinWidth` from `Column` 2 as well. Here's the modifications:

```
<!-- Content Area -->
<Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
      Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="32" Width="260"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="8" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

...
```

Then the Event setting `MaxWidth`

```
this.SizeChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    double maxWidth = this.ActualWidth / 2.0;
    this.ContentGrid.ColumnDefinitions[0].MaxWidth = maxWidth;
}
```

Comment: +1 for a creative solution. I had hit this problem and used only fixed width columns instead, but then of course you need to set the size of the right column (as you are doing). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Having a smiliar situation e.g.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <ColumnDefinitions Width="Auto"/>
  <ColumnDefinitions Width="12"/>
  <ColumnDefinitions Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

With splitter in the middle,

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

My goal:

> AutoWidth in 1st column prevented splitter from 'trespassing' onto it. Hence I Wanted to set limit on splitter to prevent it from pushing 3rd column (weighted width- *) over the boundaries.

Using IValueConverter to return half width of Mainwindow as a boundary,

```
return (double)value/2;
```

Tried (not working),

```
<SomeContent Grid.Column="2"
    MinWidth="{Binding
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
               Path=ActualWidth,
               Converter={StaticResource minWidthConverter}}"/>
```

Also tried (also not working),

```
<AnotherContent Grid.Column="0"
    MaxWidth="{Binding
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
               Path=ActualWidth,
               Converter={StaticResource minWidthConverter}}"/>
```

**Finally** (&**working**),

```
<GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    MaxWidth="{Binding
               RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
               Path=ActualWidth,
               Converter={StaticResource minWidthConverter}}"/>
```

Who would have thought of setting the splitter itself =D